# how to display none using media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How to display none div in inside div using media queries

id="flexnav-menu-button" 
I want hide this one of media screen 470px;

```
  <header class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    <a href="index.aspx">
                        <img class="logo" title="just search4u" alt="justsearch4u.com"
                            style="width: 158px; height: 114px; margin-top: -19px" src="../Images/justsearchforu1.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                   <div class="flexnav-menu-button" id="flexnav-menu-button" >Menu</div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flexnav" id="flexnav" runat="server" data-breakpoint="800">
                            <li id="a" runat="server" class="active"><a href="Index.aspx"><b style="color: #000" class="index_head">Home</b></a>

                            </li>
                            <li id="b" runat="server"><a href="about.aspx"><b style="color: #000" class="index_head">About</b></a></li>


                            <li id="c" runat="server"><a href="contact.aspx"><b style="color: #000" class="index_head">Contact</b></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/u9hmt0zn/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 470px) {
    #flexnav-menu-button {
        display:none;
    }
}
```